# Meaning of this error message python version conflicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, environment

While trying to install package: line-profiler-pycharm, I install it using pip inside my conda environment called `wcs`. But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
 22:01  Error running 'prep_network': Could not 
do Profile Lines execution because the
python package 'line-profile-pycharm' is not 
installed to Python 3.8 (wcs): Python 3.10.5 (/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/envs/wcs/bin/python)
```

Why does it show to python 3.8 and then python 3.10 after the colon `:`?

I checked the python versions inside my `˜/anaconda3/wcs/bin/python` , I can see `python 3.11` and `python3.10`, `Python3.8` does not even exist in there.

Comment: You probably have a python 3.8 on your system, and accidentally used that to install the package.

Comment: With the Conda environment activated, try with `python -m pip install line-profile-pycharm`.

Comment: Btw, I notice the error doesn't appear to originate from Python code; I assume it's from some shell setup?

Comment: `python 3.1*`?? That isn't not a version, so it's unclear if you mean python 3.11, or something else.

Comment: that was a typo @9769953, 3.1* instead of 3.11; Thanks for highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `$ which pip` and compare with `$ which python`.
They likely come from different places.
To avoid the mismatch, prefer `$ python -m pip install ...`

Going forward, it would be best to add "line-profiler-pycharm"
to your project's `environment.yml`,
and then `$ conda env update` will properly install it for you.

If your config gets messed up, it is always harmless
to discard the environment (anaconda3/envs/wcs) and
use `$ conda env update` to re-create it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks @J_H for your answer, but it didn't work. I think pycharm has something to do with updating an old environment namespace (just my hunch). So, today I will create a new environment using my old yml file and link pycharm interpreter to the new environment. If it works, I will request you to add this final brute force solution after your three lines, then I will accept it. thanks a lot!

Comment: Hunch clarfied: When it is too messed up, create a new env with your yml, then it works. I think this is a pycharm (IDE) specific problem with resolving namespaces. But I still think, this is more of a harder reset compared to your three steps, could you add this to your answer after last line?